# Getting rid of spaces after text in R

Tags: r

I have a column of a large data frame containing regions sampled. However I have found that a number of the entries contain spaces following the regions name e.g. "East ". This is causing me problems for my analysis as R reads this as a different region to "East". Is there a way I can get rid of these spaces?

I have tried:

```
gsub("  ", "", df$Region)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Apologies for my ignorance I am new to R.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your code will replace only occurrences of two spaces, not single spaces.  Is this intentional?

Comment: I was trying to indicate a space after where the text would go. when I do: sort(unique(as.character(df$Region))) I still get ones with a space after the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df$Region <- gsub(" +$", "", df$Region)
```

`+` detects one or more spaces together, and `$` detects the end of the string. That way you remove all spaces together, no matter how many there are, but only at the end of the string.